# Booting Debian from USB stick fails although Secure Boot is disabled

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, debian

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd gen.; 2015) with Windows 8. I used Unetbootin to create a bootable USB stick with Debian Testing (the USB stick is FAT32 formatted). When I plug in the USB stick, reboot, press + hold F12, select "USB HDD: USB DISK 2.0" in the menu and then press Enter I immediately get the same screen again (with the different boot options) instead of the laptop booting from the USB stick. Why?

I read about UEFI Secure Boot and thought that this is the problem, but I disabled it according to the description found on [this website](http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/) and the problem still remains.

**Note** I just tried the USB stick on the Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (1st gen; 2013) and there booting works, so it's not the USB stick it seems.

**Solution** Based on whs' suggestion, I went to Startup and set UEFI/Legacy Boot to Both. It then worked, I could boot to Windows and from the USB stick (note: setting it to Legacy only will not allow to boot Windows anymore).

Comment: In addition to secure boot off you have to set Legacy mode on.

Comment: No problem. Any time.